Sequence converges to another point equivalent to negating it converges to that point?
Given a sequence $(x_n)$ in some metric space $(M,d)$, it is clear that the negation of this sequence converging to a specific point $x\in M$ is
$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_+,\exists n_0\ge n, d(x_{n_0},x)\ge\epsilon$$
But, does saying that it converges to any other point negates that it converges to $x$? That is, saying
$$\forall y\in M-\{x\},\forall\epsilon>0,\exists n_0\in\mathbb{Z}_+, \forall n\ge n_0,d(x_n,y)<\epsilon\;\;$$
I'm inclined to say that this second statement is not a negation of converging to $x$. But I cannot come up with a good reason why, other than this  statement is not equal to the first statement (which is no doubt a correct negation). I'd really appreciate if someone can help me to clarify this issue.

A sequence in  a metric space cannot have two different limits.

Meaning this second statement is a proper negation, right?

Yes, it is  a negation of the first.

You mean, a negation of convergence to $x$? (the first statement is a negation of convergence. not def. of convergence to $x$)

If we write $C_x$ for the statement that the sequence converges to $x$, then we have $C_x \land C_y \to x = y$, which means that $C_x \land x \neq y \to \neg C_y$. That is, for $x \neq y$, we have that $C_x$ and $C_y$ are mutually exclusive, but this doesn't mean that one is the negation of the other (in the sense that $C_x \equiv \neg C_y$), because we don't have the other implication $\neg C_y \to C_x$.
